# adding one more view in the middle of the listview

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I'm trying to put multiple views into a listview, but even when i use getItemViewType() and getViewTypeCount), it doesn't work, the error is : "ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException length=2; index=2;

Here's my code :

```
public class SearchAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private static final int TYPE_MOVIE = 1;
private static final int TYPE_ADS = 2;
private Context context;
private List<MovieObject> movies;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public SearchAdapter(Context context, List<MovieObject> movies) {
    this.context = context;
    this.movies = movies;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int separator = (movies.size() / 2) + 1;
    if (position == separator) {
        return TYPE_ADS;
    } else {
        return TYPE_MOVIE;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return movies.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return movies.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder h = null;
    ViewHolderAds h2 = null;
    if (v == null) {
        h = new ViewHolder();
        switch (type) {
        case TYPE_MOVIE:
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_search, null);
            h = new ViewHolder();
            break;
        case TYPE_ADS:
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_ads, null);
            h2 = new ViewHolderAds();
            v.setTag(h2);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        v.setTag(h);
    } else {
        if (type == TYPE_MOVIE) {
            h = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        } else {
            h2 = (ViewHolderAds) v.getTag();
        }

    }
    return v;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv_title, tv_date, tv_certification, tv_runtime;
}

private class ViewHolderAds {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
private static final int TYPE_MOVIE = 1;
private static final int TYPE_ADS = 2;
```

with

```
private static final int TYPE_MOVIE = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ADS = 1;
```

internally android uses those constants as index for an array of views, of size returned by `getViewTypeCount()`, and you can not have an array of size 2 with index 2 (thats what the exception is telling you)

Comment: Okay, thank you it's working, but on an related note, when i do this, i lost one my movie object, the one which was supposed to be on the position : int separator = (movies.size() / 2) + 1; How can i add one more view instead of replacing ?

Comment: I don`t get it. Could you rephrase?

Comment: What i want is to put one more object, that is not a movie (it's an ad) between two movies. I intended to put the ad in the middle of the page. But when i'm using this method, it overlaps the movie an place the ad instead.

Comment: well you have to arrange the items inside the dataset the way you want to display it. If I were in you I do not rely on the position, but I will associate the information about the type of the object I want to show with the item I am going to show